# Using Variable and XPATH to select value of element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following snipset of code

```
<xsl:variable name="cId" value="c001" />

<clients>
    <c001>Mario</c001>
    <c002>Luigi</c002>
</clients>
```

And Based on variable's value, I need to select the correct element under clients.

For Example. variable cId is assigned with value c001. 
Is there a way for me to select the value of c001 using XPATH or XSLT?

I can do it this way, but seems like for-loop is a little bit over kill

```
<xsl:variable name="cId" value="c001" />
<xsl:for-each select="/clients/*">         
    <xsl:variable name="cNode" select="local-name()"/>         
    <xsl:if test="$cNode = $cId">                 
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

The code above will return "Mario"

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

**This question is not very clear, but you probably want something like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">

 <my:catalog>
  <catalog>
    <client>
      <clientid>c001</clientid>
      <clientid>c003</clientid>
      <clientid>c004</clientid>
      <clientid>c005</clientid>
    </client>
  </catalog>
 </my:catalog>

 <xsl:variable name="vCat"
  select="document('')/*/my:catalog"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/clients/*
       [name() = $vCat/catalog/client/clientid]
         /text()
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<clients>
    <c001>Stars Company</c001>
    <c002>Bold Unregistered</c002>
</clients>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
Stars Company
```